# java executable jar creation

Tags: java

How to Create Executable jar file from .java file. Having only one java file dm.java which created using awt and applet. I need to create executable jar with icon or with image. By clicking the jar it will open as an application. Its possible ? please help me

Comment: Why do you want an applet as an executable jar?

Comment: Why code using AWT in this millennium?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-362/heliossr2), right click on project ->'Export'->'Java'->'Runnable Jar File', fill in all fields and press 'Finish'. Most jars exported with this method can be double clicked to run, however some require starting from command line.

Comment: can anyone send me the steps i need to do from .java file to creating jar in cmd mode. this java file not contains any package also

Comment: right ns by LFA2711 and also select "extract required libraries into jar" before you finish all the libraries will be included.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to include file MANFEST.MF into META-INF directory of your jar. The manifest must contain attribute Main`-Class`. Its value is the fully qualified class name of your main class, i.e. class that is the entry point to your application.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html for details.

Icon is different. If you are speaking about icon that appears on the left upper corner of your application window use `frame.setIconImage(image)`. 
If you are asking about the icon that appears on your command window this is platform specific and could be achieved by running script.

Comment: can anyone send me the steps i need to do from .java file to creating jar in cmd mode. this java file not contains any package also.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest is to export to jar file using eclipse.  otherwise, you will need to use java -jar command.

to make that double click happen, double clickin on the jar file will automatically the jar.  otherwise, u can always create a shortcut (assumin ur on win) to the jar file. and then u can double click that shortcut to open up ur jar file

Comment: can anyone send me the steps i need to do from .java file to creating jar in cmd mode. this java file not contains any package also

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to launch applets free-floating on the desk top.  JWS can install desktop shortcuts & menu items for apps., both with icons.

JWS uses Jar files only.  To Jar your applet, do something like..

```
prompt>dir
dm.java
prompt>javac dm.java             // compile the source
prompt>dir
dm.class
dm$1.class
dm.java
prompt>jar -cf *.class dm.jar    // archive the classes
prompt>dir
dm.class
dm$1.class
dm.jar
dm.java
prompt>
```

It is not strictly necessary to include a manifest in a JWS application, and there is almost no point for a JWS applet.  The applet class is instead specified in the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) file used to launch the applet.  The JNLP file also contains information on the shortcuts and icons.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a executable .jar with a manifest that contains Main-Class:  ,  it will work by double clicking BUT ONLY if you have the correct file associations setup on your system.  For this to be correct, you need to install a RECENT version of Java.   Some of the older versions of Java wont setup the file association that your end-user needs.   You can guarantee it will work only by providing them a batch script that creates the file association, like so:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: this .bat script creates a file association for executable .jar files
ECHO Creating .jar file association...
ECHO JAVA_HOME is %JAVA_HOME%
IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME GOTO :FAIL
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Executable Jar File" /f
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell" /ve /f
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell\open" /ve /f
ECHO REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%*" /f
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%**" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\jarfile" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Executable Jar File" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell" /ve /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open" /ve /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%*" /f
ECHO Finished creating .jar file association for executable .jar files.
PAUSE
GOTO EOF
:FAIL
ECHO Script failed. JAVA_HOME not defined.
PAUSE
```